# How to fix "Segfault in Cherokee"?

Tags: php, http, cherokee, fcgi, php-cgi

I keep getting the following in my mail.

```
The Cherokee 'panic action' script, /usr/bin/cherokee-panic,
was called for pid <number> ().

This means there was a problem with the program, such as a segfault.
However, the executable could not be found for process <number>.
It may have died unexpectedly, or you may not have permission to
debug the process.
```

I think it is php related, as I got a few php-cgi zombie processes.
My settings are:

```
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 255
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 8
```

I went through all my logs, no warnings, not even notices. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try "tracing" Cherokee. You'll need to make sure you have tracing enabled (`cherokee -i` to find out.) If you don't have tracing enabled, you'll need to go and re-compile Cherokee from source (with the `--enable-trace` option).

With cherokee enabled with tracing, you can then kill all of the cherokee/cherokee worker processes, and run:

```
sudo CHEROKEE_TRACE="all" cherokee-worker
```

This will give you loads of messages, but if you just leave it on until it panics (it should close and dump you back to shell), then you can look at the logs and see what has gone wrong.